# Stop when I have collected all 3 toys

Tags: r, random, dplyr, simulation, tibble

I am trying to do this simulation in R: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4M9aNcBygPs&list=WL&index=100

I have got as far as making a random order of toys. But what code can I use that will tell me when I have got all 3 toys?

```
rep("mouse", 3000) -> mouse
rep("dolphin", 5000) -> dolphin
rep("train", 2000) -> train

c(mouse, dolphin, train) -> toy

library(tibble);library(dplyr)

tibble(toy) %>% 
    slice_sample(prop = 1, replace = FALSE) -> # randomises order
  df
```

Comment: `max(match(c("mouse", "dolphin", "train"), toy))`

Comment: max(match(c("mouse", "dolphin", "train"), df$toy)) to relate to the setup shown